# how to apply dataframe rows into a defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

I have a function so that I could add a name and its lats and longs and at first I add them line by line

```
 `def add_coordinate():
         # Coordinate location name
    name: str
         # Longitude
    longitude: Numeric
         # Latitude
    latitude: Numeric
`
geo = Geo()
 
# Add coordinate point, add name and latitude and longitude
geo.add_coordinate(name="VKO",longitude=55.60,latitude=37.26)
geo.add_coordinate(name="MLE",longitude=4.18,latitude=73.52)
```

Now I have a dataframe with the data I wanted to add, how could I loop the dataframe to apply these rows to the function?

| IATA | LAT2 | LONG2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VKO | 55.600000 | 37.267778 |
| MLE | 4.184722 | 73.518889 |
| DWC | 24.916944 | 55.168056 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to apply the function on the rows, as follows:

(assuming `df` is the name of your dataframe`):

```
df.apply(lambda x: geo.add_coordinate(name=x.IATA, longitude=x.LONG2, latitude=x.LAT2), axis=1)
```